# PHP delete all subdirectories in a directory having expired date?

Tags: php, directory, unlink, rmdir

There is a directory `/home/example/public_html/users/files/`. Within the directory there are subdirectories with random names like `2378232828923_1298295497`.

How do I completely delete the subdirectories which have creation date > 1 month?

There is a good script that I use to delete files, but it don't work with dirs:

```
$seconds_old = 2629743; //1 month old
$directory = "/home/example/public_html/users/files/";

            if( !$dirhandle = @opendir($directory) )
                        return;

             while( false !== ($filename = readdir($dirhandle)) ) {
                     if( $filename != "." && $filename != ".." ) {
                                $filename = $directory. "/". $filename;

                             if( @filectime($filename) < (time()-$seconds_old) )
                                      @unlink($filename); //rmdir maybe?
                     }
             }
```

Comment: you can use rmdir(), and you can write a recursive delete algorythm.

Comment: For first - remove all `@` from your code and forget that it is an operator in php.

Comment: I would strongly discourage the use of @ as not only does it surpress any errors which you may want to catch; but it is a huge hog on performance.

Comment: @Frederico: it is not a big performance degradation (to be clear, it is tiny), but supressing of errors is the bigger reason to never use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a recursive function for this.

```
function remove_dir($dir)
{
    chdir($dir);
    if( !$dirhandle = @opendir('.') )
        return;

    while( false !== ($filename = readdir($dirhandle)) ) {
        if( $filename == "." || $filename = ".." )
            continue;

        if( @filectime($filename) < (time()-$seconds_old) ) {
            if (is_dir($filename)
                remove_dir($filename);
            else 
                @unlink($filename);
        }
    }
    chdir("..");
    rmdir($dir);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php
    $dirs = array();
    $index = array();
    $onemonthback = strtotime('-1 month');
    $handle = opendir('relative/path/to/dir');
    while($file = readdir($handle){
        if(is_dir($file) && $file != '.' && $file != '..'){
            $dirs[] = $file;
                $index[] = filemtime( 'relative/path/to/dir/'.$file );
        }
}    
closedir($handle);


    asort( $index );

    foreach($index as $i => $t) {

        if($t < $onemonthback) {
            @unlink('relative/path/to/dir/'.$dirs[$i]);
        }


}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If PHP runs on a Linux server, you could use a shell command, to improve performance (a recursive PHP function can be inefficient in very large directories):

`shell_exec('rm -rf '.$directory);`

Comment: Maybe you should mention that's an incredibly dangerous command to run

Comment: It' exactly as dangerous as the php-native implementation above: they do exactly the same thing and they do it as "www-data" user (or the configured Apache user), the only difference is that this take less time to run, even though on some shared hosting will not run if the administrator has disabled the shell_exec function